# How to Force Visual Studio to Use a Specific Version of DNX

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, dnvm

I was messing around with the dnvm, and I ran dnvm upgrade, putting me into beta5.  However, the project I am working on is staying in beta4 (at least for now).

I have been attempting to revert and failing.  I have gone as far as to delete the runtime folder.  Now, when I open the project or attempt to make a new one I get the following error:

[image]

This is expected because I deleted the folder.  However, I want to use dnx-clr-beta4.  My dnvm list is as follows:

[image]

What do I need to do to make Visual Studio look for beta4 instead?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the DNX version inside the global.json file which lives on the root directory of your solution (like [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/239906e943b576d4ffd80bdaf855376aef737c63/samples/1.0.0-beta4/global.json)).

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta4"
    }
}
```

You may need to restart the Visual Studio.

The other way is to configure this through project properties dialog inside Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: The restart will be fixed in the next version of visual studio. You can change the version in the file real time and VS will update.