# Bluemix MVC Starter code is not working locally

Tags: ibm-cloud

I started using Blue Mix, and download starter code, but once i tried to compile that in VS 2015, its showing me library not found..

Can someone help with that ?

Rakesh Yadav

Comment: Starter code for which runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET 5 starter code in Bluemix is currently written for the beta3 release and VS may now be trying to use the newer beta4 or beta5 releases. Normally you can [change that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309356/how-to-force-visual-studio-to-use-a-specific-version-of-dnx) under your project's properties, but given the major changes between beta3 and beta4 (it wasn't even called DNX in beta3) I don't think it's possible to compile the starter code with the latest VS. The older [getting started instructions](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/master#getting-started) point to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527980 for VS, I would suggest trying that for now.